# I want to CRUD the value of the FireStore in the method

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

・ What I want to do.
I have stored the document ID of the currently accessed room in user collection>document>field>documentID.
I want to retrieve it and rewrite the document in the room collection.

But I can't rewrite it.
I want to know how to get the data and rewrite it.

[The document ID in the user collection is the user ID.]

I want to retrieve the field in the following method

```
void _onConferenceTerminated(message) async {
   
//[Image 1] I get the documentID being accessed from the documentID in the field of the user collection

final user = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(uid()).get();
final getDocId = user.data['documentID']

//[*image2]Use it to access the room document and reduce the roomCount

    final setRoomCount = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
        .collection('room')
        .doc(getDocId)
        .set({'roomCount': roomCount - 1});
  }

//Get the user ID
  String uid() {
    final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!
    final String uid = user.uid.toString();
    return uid
```

[image1]
[image]

[image2]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use .update() instead of .set() if you want to change only one field. I also recommend you to use FieldValue.increment(value) which is built-in function in firestore.

Value could be both int and double.

```
FieldValue.increment(1)
FieldValue.increment(2.0)
```

Also, you can use negative numbers to decrease the value. In your case, you can try the below code.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("room")
        .doc(getDocId)
        .update({"roomCount": FieldValue.increment(-1)}
```

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I want to change the field directly from the method.

Currently, there is a global variable called roomCount, and I want to change
I am using FutureBuilder to display it.

However, the method in the question text is
It is a method that runs when you leave the room.
I thought it would be better to do -1 directly from the field roomCount.

Therefore, I would like to know how to change the value of the field directly.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a code sample for decreasing the value directly. Please check my answer.